# I am being badgered to work hours I can't handle, what do I do?

Tags: new-job

I have been at my new job for a few weeks. I was upfront during the interview and informed them that I would have to work limited hours, 4-5 hour shifts 20-25 hours a week. I have screwed up feet that cause me so much pain, and I have possibly been walking around for seven years with a torn MCL.

I am now being badgered into working more hours then I am okay with. They keep bringing it up, I had to buy black shoes because they didn't want me wearing my blue ones that have the memory foam that help my feet a little. Now they want me to wear my blue ones because they think I will be able to be on my feet longer. 
I like the job because it pays weekly and it is close to home so I don't have to use as much gas. But I am starting. To think it isn't worth it. One of the line cooks quit so now they are saying I HAVE to work more hours to cover the spots he is needed. I doubt a doctor's note would stop them from hounding me.

Comment: You either make it work, or you start looking for another job, or you do the best you can and hope they don't fire you. We can't tell you which.

Comment: You can decide it's not worth it and quit. Or you can threaten to quit. Or something...

Comment: "I doubt a doctor note would stop them from hounding me." I'd say you are right on the money on this one. In general, they are looking out for themselves not for you and they couldn't care less what happens to you. The only thing that matters to them is that they get what they want or need from you regardless of the consequences to you. If you can handle their badgering without giving in, stay. If not, consider scheduling interviews elsewhere.

Comment: Is there anything in your contract about maximum hours you can work or anything?

Answer (score 7):

You describe a situation where you were up front with the prospective employer about your needs, but they were not realistic when hiring you about their ability to support those needs.

This employer will continue to have a struggle to accept your legitimate desire for part-time work.

You have 2 options at this point:

1. Find a new job where the employer only wants someone part-time with close to the amount of hours you are looking to work
2. Find someone else who also only wants part-time work that can work with you - and introduce them to your company - this MAY suit them and if you can accomplish this - it is likely to give you a good outcome.  This is a quite challenging thing to achieve - but if you know someone with similar skills to you that also wants part-time work then is worth pursuing.

Best of luck in resolving your challenge!

Answer (score 1):

They will continue hounding you until you leave, you give in, or they give up. You want them to give up. Which means first you don't leave, and you never give in. Most importantly, in order to make them give up, you must *each single time* someone wants you to work more tell them in the most serious way that there is absolutely no way that you will ever, ever give in to their demands.

That's simple psychology: If someone tries to get something and doesn't get it but sees a chance they might get, they will try again and again and again. If they don't see a chance to get what they want, they will give up a lot quicker. That also means: If they ask you, don't come up with excuses. Excuses give them hope. The proper way: "I would like you to work this afternoon". "I told you that I cannot work more than 20-25 hours a week, so I will not work this afternoon. Before you ask me again to do more work, please remember that I cannot and will not work more than 20-25 hours a week".

PS. They made it clear that there is no business reason for you to wear uncomfortable black shoes instead of the comfortable blue ones.